# Specified cast is not valid in C#

Tags: c#

I have a column which is of type bigint in the database table. I want it to retrieve and assign it to variable in C# as shown below in the example.

**Example**:

```
obj.Total1 = (Int32)reader["Slno"] != null ? (Int32)reader["Slno"] : 0;
obj.Total2 = (Int32)reader["Rlno"] != null ? (Int32)reader["Rlno"] : 0;
```

**Note**: Here `Slno` and `Rlno` are of type bigint in database table.

**Error**: Following is the error message.

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: What are the values that you want to cast exactly?

Comment: What is Total1 and 2 type?

Comment: Is the reader array SqlDataReader ? did you call Read() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigInt needs to be mapped to `long` which is the equivalent 64bit integer value in C#.

Also, you should alter your code to something like this:

```
int slnoCol = reader.GetOrdinal("Slno");
int rlnoCol = reader.GetOrdinal("Rlno");

obj.Total1 = !reader.IsDBNull(slnoCol) ? reader.GetInt64(slnoCol) : (long)0;
obj.Total2 = !reader.IsDBNull(rlnoCol) ? reader.GetInt64(rlnoCol) : (long)0;
```

EDIT:

After noticing your comment that Total1 and Total2 are `int`, you also need to change them to `long`

```
public long Total1 { get; set; }
public long Total2 { get; set; }
```

This is because `int` is a 32bit integer which cannot store the same max value as a 64bit integer which is what you are using in your table.

Comment: is `ReadInt64` need extension or assembly reference. Because it is giving error that `Does not contain definition of ReadInt64`. I am using PostgreSQL database.

Comment: @Meem - My bad, typing it without double checking, the method is called `GetInt64`, not `ReadInt64`!

Answer (score 4):

SQL's `BigInt` maps to a `long` in C#, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting a "**specified cast is not valid**", when my table was empty.

so I changed my code like so:

```
while (reader.Read())
    max = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

Added a check for `DBNull`:

```
while (reader.Read())
    max = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(0);
```